# c++ count words in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a function that gets a string and count how many words there are in the string and how many letters. And then calculate the average of it.
A word in a string is a sequence of letters and numbers separated by one or more spaces.

First of all I have to check if the string is correct. The string must contain only lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and numbers only.

i didnt menage to count all sort of words correctly and also my function doesnt count the last letter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 50


float checkString(char string[]) {

float wordCounter = 0;
float letterCounter = 0;
bool isLegit = true;

int i = 0;


while (isLegit) {

        if (((string[i] >= 48 && string[i] <= 57) ||
            (string[i] >= 65 && string[i] <= 90) ||
            (string[i] >= 97 && string[i] <= 122 ))) {

            for (int j = 0; j <= strlen(string); j++) {



                if ((string[j - 1] != ' ' && string[j] == ' ' && 
 string[i + 1] != ' ')
                    || j == (strlen(string) - 1)) {
                    wordCounter++;

                }

                else if (string[j] != ' ') {
                    letterCounter++;
                    cout << string[j];
                }



            }
            cout << " The avareage is : " << (letterCounter / 
wordCounter) << endl;
            isLegit = false;
        }
            else {
            return -1;
            isLegit = false;

        }



    }



cout << "Number of words " << wordCounter << endl;
cout << "Number of letters " <<letterCounter << endl;

}


int main() {

char string[SIZE];
cout << "please enter a sentence " << endl;
cin.getline(string, SIZE);
checkString(string);
}
```

Comment: Advice: Avoid magic numbers. Don't write `48`, use a literal `'0'`.

Comment: I suggest you look at the <regex> standard library as the underpinning of your program.

Comment: @VorpalSword Bringing in regex for this sounds like overkill and OP will  probably spend a lot more time trying to understand that than solving this with more conventional methods.

Comment: i cannot use extra libraries

Comment: @OmerTesler It's not an extra library. It's part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Wow. ````char string[]```` in C++. . .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `char[]` for strings, I suggest that you use `std::string` which can grow and shrink dynamically. It's one of the most common types to use in the standard C++ library. You can also make use of `stringstream`s which lets you put a string inside it and then you can extract the contents of the stringstream using `>>`, just like when reading from `std::cin`.

Example with comments in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>  // std::stringstream
#include <string>   // std::string

// use std::string instead of a char[]
float checkString(const std::string& string) {
    // put the string in a stringstream to extract word-by-word
    std::istringstream is(string);

    unsigned words = 0;
    unsigned letters = 0;

    std::string word;
    // extract one word at a time from the stringstream:
    while(is >> word) {
        // erase invalid characters:
        for(auto it = word.begin(); it != word.end();) {

            // Don't use magic numbers. Put the character literals in the code so
            // everyone can see what you mean
            if((*it>='0' && *it<='9')||(*it>='A' && *it<='Z')||(*it>='a' && *it<='z')) {
                // it was a valid char
                ++it;
            } else {
                // it was an invalid char, erase it
                it = word.erase(it);
            }
        }

        // if the word still has some characters in it, make it count:
        if(word.size()) {
            ++words;
            letters += word.size();
            std::cout << '\'' << word << "'\n"; // for debugging
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words " << words << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of letters " << letters << "\n";
    std::cout << "The average number of letters per word is "
              << static_cast<float>(letters) / words << '\n';

    return 0.f; // not sure what you are supposed to return, but since the function
                // signature says that you should return a float, you must return a float.
}

int main() {
    checkString(" Hello !!! World, now  let's see  if  it works. ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an additional answer. This answer is based on "more-modern" C++ and the usage of algorithms. You want to solve 3 tasks:

1. Check, if string is OK and matched to your expectations
2. Count the number of words in the given string
3. Count the number of letters
4. Calculate the ratio of words/letters

For all this you may use existings algorithms from the C++ standard library. In the attached example code, you will see a one-liner for each task.

The statements are somehow very simple, so that I will not explain much more. If there should be a question, I am happy to answer.

Please see here one possible example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <cctype>

std::regex re("\\w+");

std::tuple<bool, int, int, double> checkString(const std::string& str) {

    // Check if string consists only of allowed values, spaces or alpha numerical
    bool stringOK{ std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](const char c) { return std::isalnum(c) || std::isspace(c); }) };

    // Count the number of words
    int numberOfWords{ std::distance(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(),str.end(), re, 1), {}) };

    // Count the number of letters
    int numberOfLetters{ std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isalnum) };

    // Return all calculated values
    return std::make_tuple(stringOK, numberOfWords, numberOfLetters, static_cast<double>(numberOfWords)/ numberOfLetters);
}

int main() {

    // Ask user to input string
    std::cout << "Please enter a sentence:\n";

    // Get string from user
    if (std::string str{}; std::getline(std::cin, str)) {

        // Analyze string
        auto [stringOk, numberOfWords, numberOfLetters, ratio] = checkString(str);

        // SHow result
        std::cout << "\nString content check: " << (stringOk ? "OK" : "NOK") << "\nNumber of words:      "
            << numberOfWords << "\nNumber of letters:    " << numberOfLetters << "\nRatio:                " << ratio << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are many more other possible solutions. But, because of the simplicity of this solution, I showed this variant.